# Eclipse error due to jvm

Tags: kali-linux

When I run eclipse on linux, the icon appear and later it disappear(crash). I want to say I have error in installing eclipse. Please tell me the requirements of installation in eclipse. Whether it cause of jdk 1.6.0 ?

Comment: Try another java version,maybe the official from oracle,or another eclipse version,on some distro(debian 7 for example) eclipse was outdated

Answer (score 0):

Download eclipse from their site and just unzip the files and try opening with the eclipse icon in the unzipped folder.Unzip using the command

```
$ tar -zxvf {file.tar.gz}
```

If java is needed then use the following commands(if you have a debian based system). Check if Java is not already installed:

```
java -version
```

If it returns "The program java can be found in the following packages", Java hasn't been installed yet, so execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

This will install the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) and Java Development Kit (JDK),

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

Comment: I mean on linux not on window, sir.

Comment: Sorry!!!! it was my bad. I have changed my answer. Hope this works for you. But first check your system if it is 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: Thanks, but I have still error in installing jdk.It is unable to locate package.

Comment: May this will help have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136407/eclipse-luna-not-working-kali-linux